# What is the process for installing MATE desktop into Centos Stream 9?

Tags: centos, mate-desktop

From that little info that is available I gather that the group "MATE Desktop" has been renamed into something different. This is the group that many write-ups and videos show how to install. Since its renaming/hiding from EPEL there is little info. So, how?

Comment: `sudo dnf grouplist`